# iOS: UITableView inside UITableViewCell with dynamic cell height

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I want to implement `UITableView` inside `UITableViewCell` with dynamic height of cell according to inside `UITableView` content size. How can I implement this any suggestions?
I want layout something like this...

**Code work:**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat { 
    let identifier = "OrderHistoryTVCell" let cell: OrderHistoryTVCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier) as? OrderHistoryTVCell 
    let tableInnerContentSize = cell.tableInner.contentSize.height 
    let nn = cell.viewAfterTable.frame.height+tableInnerContentSize 
    return nn 
}
```

[image]

Comment: Show us your `prototype-cell` image.

Comment: I have updated required view here...

Comment: Are you trying to implement expandable tableView ???

Comment: No...it is not expandable...
For an example...I want to create food order history, which can have multiple food items within cell (inner table), and main table can have multiple orders.

Comment: Please let me know...where should I use delegates methods for inner tableView which is inside cell...
In UITableviewCell class or in ViewController?

Comment: I am trying to do this in:
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
    {
        let identifier = "OrderHistoryTVCell"
        let cell: OrderHistoryTVCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier) as? OrderHistoryTVCell
        let tableInnerContentSize = cell.tableInner.contentSize.height
        let nn = cell.viewAfterTable.frame.height+tableInnerContentSize
        
        return nn
    }

Comment: Are you using auto layout for tablview?

Answer (score 0):

use following:

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView! //connect the table view

//do following in viewDidLoad method
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100 //Your estimated height
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Also set these two properties of UILable from Attributes inspector section of storyboard:

- lines to 0
- Line break to word wrap

or you can also set these properties from code:

```
self.lblxyz.numberOfLines = 0
self.lblxyz.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
```

Note - Add constraint properly in table view cell.

Comment: no. It helps even when cell are of different size. I have implemented it and it works according to the size of textView. If it has less data it will shrink and if it has more data it will increase its height

Comment: This is property so it first called when your VC loads but delegate method called every time when your generated. What if you reload your cell with new height. At that time this property not called but already setted. Yeah! it works too no doubt but there is difference in the user intraction performance.

Comment: I am getting data from api so i am also using tableview reload. Though it works for me. First I used to put after tableView.reloadData() line but then when i used same in viewDidLoad then it also works. Here UITableViewAutomaticDimension means that it always accepts the automatic height according to the constraints set in the content view of that tableViewCell.

Comment: sorry? what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

You have to do something like this:

1. In ui `Master-Item #` is be your section header. So take UILabel and add it as a section header.
2. Your sub-item is the `prtotype-cell` cell which contains one label.

**Constraints for label inside cell.**

- In your `cell` first add `UIView` with constraints as follows:

  1. Top , Bottom , Leading, Bottom to `superView` as `0`.
- Now add label and give constraints as follow.

  1. Top , Bottom , Leading, Bottom to `UIView` as `8`.
  2. Give height constraint as per your requirement.
  3. Give height relationship from `=` to `>=`.
  4. Set `label` property line to 0 from storyboard.

Implement this lines in

```
//MARK:- TableView

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat{
    return 60 // return header height
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    // return your section header i.e. master item label

}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat{
    return 50;
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat{
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

public func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int{
// return number of section i.e. total count of master item.
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
// returns number of cells in each section
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    // return your custom cell here
    //eg:
    // cell.labelFood.text = your data
}
```

**NOTE** Don't forget to bind `delegate` and `dataSource` of tableView.

Comment: I am not using auto layout, designing pattern is scaling.

Comment: @PPreeti First of all you cannot `dequeue` cell in `heightForRow` method. Only do it in `cellForRow` method. Second add your code work in question to let us see what actually you are doing.

Answer (score -2):

use this code in viewDidLoad()

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 350
 self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Use this Delegate

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
            return UITableViewAutomaticDimension

        }
```

Comment: @PPreeti  Are you using custom cell or not?

Answer (score -3):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
  {
        self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 160
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
  }
```

Also set these two properties of UILable.

```
 @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
```

1. label.numberOfLines = 0